# Swift isa pointer remapping or other supported method swizzling

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

Do Swift classes have something like an isa pointer that can be remapped?

We've seen that Swift [uses a more static method dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24020950/404201) than objective-C, which (unless a class dervices from Foundation/NSObject) prevents the style of swizzling based on remapping method implementations at runtime.

I'm wondering how we'll implement method interception-based dynamic features like the observer pattern, notifications, etc? Currently all this stuff is provided by the Objective-C layer, and can be easily integrated into Swift. But, if we want to provide these kinds of features in a framework (or app) of our own, is it necessary to implement them in Objective-C? I would assume there's a way to do it 'natively'.

Another kind of swizzling common to objective-C is remapping the isa-pointer to generate a sub-class on the fly. Is this kind of swizzling supported in Swift? If not what ***is*** the supported way of intercepting arbitrary method invocations?

**Edit:** *As @jatoben points out, as of arm64 isa-remapping must be done by calling object_setClass() and not by accessing the value directly. This is still referred to as 'isa pointer swizzling'*

Comment: It's not safe to access isa directly in Obj-C, either: http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like both method exchanging and the isa pointer remapping technique only works if the Swift class has NSObject as a super-class (either directly or further up). It does not currently work, when the Swift class has no super-class or some other non-Foundation base class.

The following test shows this:

**Class: Birdy**

```
class Birdy: NSObject {    
    func sayHello()
    {
        print("tweet tweet")
    }    
}
```

**Class: HodorBirdy**

```
class HodorBirdy: Birdy {

    override func sayHello()
    {
        super.sayHello()
        print("hodor hodor")
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
func testExample() {        
    let birdy : Birdy = Birdy()
    object_setClass(birdy, HodorBirdy.self)
    birdy.sayHello();
}
```

And the output was as expected:

```
tweet tweet
hodor hodor
```

In this test both the base-class and sub-class were created in advance. Though they could also be created dynamically using the Objective-C runtime as long as the class has NSObject as an ancestor.

When a Swift class does not derive from the Objective-C foundation, then the compiler will favor static- or vtable-based dispatch, therefore its not clear how method interception will work at all in this case!

Unless  the language/compiler make a specific allowance for it, we'll be foregoing dynamism in favor of performance. (Interception, which is the foundation of 'dynamic' behaviors can either be done at compile-time or run-time. In the case of static- or vtable-dispatch without a virtual machine, only compile-time applies).

Comment: Related: Is it normal (within the context of a Cocoa/CocoaTouch application) for a Swift class to have no Cocoa/NSObject ancestor? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24057525/404201

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question about swift "isa" equivalent, but I think I know part of the answer to your underlying question.

*Property Observers* seem to be the built-in means for the Observer Pattern. Instead of runtime discovery of "type" (RTTI, what-have-you) it is woven in explicitly.

From 'The Swift Programming Language' page 345:

> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property's
>   value. Property observers are called every time a property's value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property's current
>   value.
>
> You can add property observers to any stored properties you define,
>   apart from lazy stored properties. You can also add property observers
>   to any inherited property (whether stored or computed) by overriding
>   the property within a subclass.
>
> You have the option to define either or both of these observers on a
>   property:
>
> - willSet is called just before the value is stored.
> - didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored.

I am not sure how this is all going to work out, but I am intrigued.

Relying on run-time type discovery also seems to run counter to strong static type orthodoxy.

Comment: So property observers are baked right in. Useful (and useful to know). But there's still many more useful things to do with the intercept pattern. . let's see if we can turn up a direct answer as well.

Comment: I also expect Haskell devotees might explain that properly written closures are the way to go. While I am hoping to uncover explicit support for concurrency, like channels and Goroutines. if only.

Comment: One of the valid uses of method interception is the ability to modularize "cross-cutting requirements" as per the Aspect Oriented Programming paradigm . . ObjC fans were enamored with its ability to do this at runtime, rather than use a compile time tool. In fact there was no formal AOP framework for ObjC as the "raw materials" for runtime interception were good enough to get by.