# Should I inherit from NSObject in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I found a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057525/swift-native-base-class-or-nsobject), but I have one more question:

I know Objective-C implement reference counter through NSObject. Is ARC still supported if NSObject is not a base class?

Comment: I don't understand why some nasty guys don't want to help at all. What they like is to find a chance to down vote somebody else's question. Please let me know what's wrong with my question?

Comment: While it's true that people downvoting should leave comments, there is lots of info on writing good questions: [ask]

Comment: You know what! Somebody feel they have power when down voting other's posts.That's so ridiculous. I know sometimes the questions are not so good. That's either because we're not very good in English or we're not expert at what we're asking. If we're experts, why should we ask? That's the purpose of this website, isn't it?

Comment: There are multiple ways in which a question can be good or bad. Many people on Stack Overflow don't have English as a first language — that's fine. But to be a "good question" usually involves clarity and background research.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding.I was trying to ask "good question" and I'll continue to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift native base class or NSObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057525/swift-native-base-class-or-nsobject)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Swift language has its own mechanism for automated reference counting that is not reliant on any particular base class. Check out the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_50).

Comment: Great to know that. Thanks. That basically means I don't need to inherit from NSObject anymore if I don't want to use NSObject's methods.