# Swift runtime documentation

Tags: swift

I have been exploring Apple's swift documentation, and now i'm here to ask.

**Is documentation about Swift's runtime available?**

I have read The Swift Programming Language book. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

I have watched WWDC videos. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

I have tried searching Swifts compiler source code, or runtime library source code.

But I've found out nothing, except few questions that actually about Obj-c [Swift function swizzling / runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019683/swift-function-swizzling-runtime)

I mean, everybody know how obj-c works. isa pointer, cmd, how do we call methods, dynamic binding and other. We know how parameters passed by registers. We can use MachOView to define all methods and classes used in binary. There are many documents about obj-c runtime, open source runtime library. Clang is open source. But what about swift?

This information exists in a centralized location for Objective-C. I'm asking for the equivalent of the Obj-C runtime library documentation.

Comment: 1. way too broad of a question 2. explicitly asking for external links, which is explicitly off topic...

Comment: @l4mpi, "too broad?" If he asked the exact same question for Objective-C, I'd simply point him to [this place](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) and nobody would dare call it too broad of a question.

Comment: @zneak "isa pointer, cmd, how do we call methods, dynamic binding and other. We know how parameters passed by registers. We can use MachOView to define all methods and classes used in binary. There are many documents about obj-c runtime, open source runtime library." - answering the multiple questions how all of these things are handled in swift is not too broad in your opinion? I mean, simply look at how long the document you linked is. That's a thousand times too broad for a SO answer... And no, just posting a link to an external resource is not an answer.

Comment: @l4mpi The main question is - "Is documentation about Swift's runtime available? Could some body point me to link about this topic?", questions are you talking about for explaining what documentation should consists.

Comment: @l4mpi question named "Swift runtime documentation" is it too broad?

Comment: @l4mpi, *I* linked to nothing. OP did. You are missing the very important context that this information exists in a centralized location for Objective-C. OP isn't asking for a single piece: he's asking for the equivalent of the ObjC runtime library documentation. Also, asking for links isn't "explicitly off topic" at all. There are 5 kinds of explicitly off-topic questions, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: @zneak I should add these words to my question, to determinate what I mean.

Comment: Pavel, as I said in my first comment, this question is off topic by definition. You're asking for an external resource. Ask apple, not StackOverflow. @zneak you linked to nothing? The link in your previous comment disagrees... and please read the close reasons again, asking for external resources of any kind is explicitly off topic: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow` - documentation == external resource. SO is for specific questions, like "How does X in swift work", not "where's a book about swift?".

Comment: @l4mpi Ok, I will delete the question. But, could you suggest any other stack-exchange site, where I could ask that question? Because I guess many other developers would ask that question, and it would be helpful if they could find answer by google.

Comment: You cannot ask that question on any stackexchange site as the cited close reason applies to all of the stackexchange sites I'm aware of (except for the software recommendation SE which is in beta right now, but I think your question is out of scope for that site). What you can do is ask specific questions about narrowly-sized topics. You could for example ask about specific behaviour of the runtime that causes you problems or interests you.

Comment: @l4mpi now I cannot delete the question.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you delete it or not, just keep in mind that this kind of question is off topic... But to elaborate on my previous comment, what is the specific problem you want to solve by accessing the runtime documentation? As long as this is reasonably scoped and not off-topic for any of the other off-topic reasons, you should turn that into a question. If you don't _have_ a specific problem yet, work on your task some more until you run into something; and then ask on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This documentation hasn't been released, and nobody outside of Apple knows if it ever will.

Since the ObjC runtime is [available](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/) on opensource.apple.com, I would imagine that the Swift runtime library source will be made available once Yosemite becomes public.

Comment: You may want to check the Swift runtime documentation here - https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Runtime.md