# swift: Equivalent objective-c runtime class

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-runtime

What is equivalent swift code for below Objective-C code. I couldn't find swift topic with runtime concept.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>    
Class class = [self class];
```

Trying to get class object of `self`?

**Update:**
Tried with below code, got error as `'UIViewController.type' doesn't conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

```
var klass: AnyClass = object_getClass(self)
```

**Note:** Found [this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068942/swift-runtime-documentation) but wouldn't helped.

Comment: please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161622/how-to-check-two-instances-are-the-same-class-type-in-swift/24165165#24165165

Comment: class is a reserved keyword in Swift. Most functionality can be use from the object itself. AnyObject has more functionality than NSObject. For instance the version property is now accessible from the object instead of first getting the class and then the version. So what do you want to do with it?

Comment: It's not duplicate with that. Reader must read question carefully.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First, it's hard to translate that code to Swift without knowing what you used that class object for in Objective-C.

In Objective-C, class objects are objects, and the type `Class` can hold a pointer to any class object. However, when Objective-C APIs are bridged to Swift, the type `Class` is converted to `AnyClass!` in Swift, where `AnyClass` is defined as `AnyObject.Type`. Types in Swift are not objects, and thus are not directly equivalent to class objects in Objective-C. However, if you intend to use an Objective-C API from Swift, it will have been bridged to expect `AnyClass` anyway, so you have to pass a type. You can get the type of any expression using `.dynamicType`; for example:

```
self.dynamicType
```

(If you really want to get the class object as an Swift object the same way as in Objective-C, and not as a Swift type, there are some [convoluted ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174510/how-to-create-a-class-array-in-swift) to do that too.)

However, your description of your problem reveals another issue. If you just want to get the type of an object, and `self` is an object, then `var klass: AnyClass = object_getClass(self)` should have worked, since `object_getClass()` takes an `AnyObject` and returns an `AnyClass`. The only explanation for it not working is if `self` is *not* an object. Your error message reveals that, indeed, `self` is a *type*, not an object.

`self` is a type if this code is running in a *class method*. You should have really given context for your code (obviously, you didn't put `Class class = [self class];` at the top level of a file), because taken out of context it's easy to misunderstand. In Objective-C Cocoa, there are *two* very different methods named `class`: an instance method, `-class`, which returns the class of the object, and a class method, `+class`, which simply returns the (class) object it's called on. Since your code is in a class method, in Objective-C, `self` points to a class object, and `[self class]` runs the class method `+class`, which just returns the object it's called on. In other words, `[self class]` is exactly identical to `self`. You should have just written `self` all along, but didn't realize it.

So the answer is that the Objective-C should have been

```
Class class = self;
```

and similarly the Swift should be

```
var klass: AnyClass = self
```

Answer (score 12):

In Swift 3, `self.dynamicType` (and `dynamicType` in general) has been removed.

You now use:

```
type(of: self)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var klass: AnyClass = object_getClass(self)
NSStringFromClass(klass)
```

Comment: Is it return class? or NSString?

Comment: There is not Class type in Swift, only AnyObject, so you can get only class name (typealias AnyClass = AnyObject.Type)

Comment: K I accept with this statement `There is not Class type in Swift`, But above answer is not correct even this statement corect.

Comment: object_getClass(self)

Comment: Did you try that? I got error as `'UIViewController.type' doesn't conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

Comment: I've written this code in `extension` of class, and method also class method.