# Swift - Get NSBundle for test target?

Tags: swift, nsbundle

In Objective C whenever I had to access the test bundle I would call

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[ClassInTestTarget class]];
```

`bundleForClass` is not available in Swift, so how do I access the test bundle?

The reason I need this is that in order to write tests for a framework I'm working on I have to use an in memory core data stack. Initially all resources were included in both main target and test target, but then I moved all these test helpers to test target only, and now the code below is returning nil which fails all my tests

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Model", withExtension: "momd")
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The corresponding Swift code is

```
// Swift 3 and later:
Bundle(for: ClassInTestTarget.self)

// Swift 1, 2:
NSBundle(forClass: ClassInTestTarget.self)
```

`ClassInTestTarget.self` return the class object for the "ClassInTestTarget" class.

Comment: This works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403718/swift-equivalent-objective-c-runtime-class

Comment: I have this working in some classes, but in others it returns bundle with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` path. Any ideas why / how to fix it?

Comment: Specifically – only happens with generic classes…

Comment: In Swift 4.1 `Bundle(for: ClassInTestTarget.self)` causes the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'ClassInTestTarget‘`.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: `ClassInTestTarget` is a *placeholder* for some class in the framework. You have to substitute the concrete name of an existing class.

Comment: Oh! I am stupid, sorry. My problem is that I want to get the bundle for the **current** test target, so that I can use the code for several test targets.