# Unable to read JSON file in Swift inside Unit Test Project

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure why but I am not able to read a json file in my Swift Unit Testing Project. What am I missing. the url is empty object and it is just jumping to the completion(nil) line 20.

[image]

Comment: Did you add it to the Build Phases of your test target?

Comment: why not just make the https call to open weather map.... its easier..

Comment: @jbiser361 True but let's say that OpenWeatherMap charges X amount whenever I make a call.

Comment: oh your right... they do

Answer (score 3):

Your code is using `Bundle.main`, but you put the file in your test target(/bundle in the code context).

I'm not sure how to get the test bundle, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596702/swift-get-nsbundle-for-test-target), you should be able to do this:

```swift
guard let url = Bundle(for: MockWeatherService.self).url(forResource: "openweathermap-response", withExtension: "json"),
```

and then the rest of your `guard` statement

Comment: I thought if I am running the test project then bundle.main will be the test project.

Comment: I think bundles are dependent on your folder structure and the targets your files are defined for, so it doesn't change. But (assuming this solution works) it will work even if `Bundle.main` was the test bundle when running tests, because it gets the bundle of that specific class.