# How can I obtain the bundle for my framework code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsbundle

Is there any way to know which bundle corresponds to a source code file?

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I have a source.swift/source.m file, inside of a Framework X. This file has a function, for instance: if it were in **Swift ->** `whoIsMyEnclosingBundle() -> NSBundle`.

What I need for this function to work properly is for me to be able to load, for instance, my Storyboards inside that framework.

**I would like to make this function general, so NO hardcoding of the bundle's name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleForClass:).

If you're not inside a class, then you could use [`+bundleWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithIdentifier:) (this does mean you need to know the identifier ahead of time). The documentation recommends that method for frameworks that need their own bundle.

Comment: In Swift 2.1 would be `NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)`

Answer (score 0):

> **In Swift**
>
> There are several ways:

**The first one is the one that will work everytime:**

- `let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: [the class you are in].self)`

> **The next two will only work in some cases:**

**- for functions not marked as `class`**

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

**- for classes bridged from Objective-C**

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: [the class you are in].classForCoder())
```

For a great explanation on `self.dynamicType` and `self` go into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24416023/2683201):