# Keychain unlock inside app, is this approach safe?

Tags: ios, authentication, keychain, touch-id

I'm using `Keychain` to permit login through `TouchID` in a remote app. My concern is about an attacker setting a breakpoint in a jailbreak device and recovering the username and password, I tried this approach to let the info the less time possible on memory.

I'd like to know if I need this level of paranoia and if I'm using the right approach.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] 
                                    initWithIdentifier:@"MyAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
if (!username || !password) {
    self.layoutState = kLayoutStateNormal;
    return;
}
// forget everything you know about my password
keychainItem = nil;
password = nil;
username = nil;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548248/is-swift-vulnerable-to-code-injection

Comment: And yes, you are correct to be paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `NSString` instances to `nil` will not remove the contents from memory, will not zero the contents, will just remove the pointer. The contents will continue to exist until that memory is re-used.

If you use "C" strings (char arrays) you can clear them. But you may need `NSString` due to the usage of the `username` and `password` in your code.

It is very hard to impossible to keep information on an iDevice from the owner/user. The best that can be dome is to increase the work factor to obtain the information.