# Are items stored using KeychainTouchID (relatively more) secure on Jailbroken devices?

Tags: ios, security, keychain, touch-id

My understanding of the iOS keychain is that is insecure on jailbroken devices.

I was wondering if one stores a value in the keychain using `kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny` as it's used in [this example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html), if there is an extra level of protection, even on jailbroken devices?

Relevant excerpt of example where text is stored into the keychain:

```
- (void)addTouchIDItemAsync {
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

// Should be the secret invalidated when passcode is removed? If not then use kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked
SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                            kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny, &error);
if (sacObject == NULL || error != NULL) {
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SecItemAdd can't create sacObject: %@", error];

    self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByAppendingString:errorString];

    return;
}

/*
    We want the operation to fail if there is an item which needs authentication so we will use
    `kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI`.
*/
NSData *secretPasswordTextData = [@"SECRET_PASSWORD_TEXT" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"SampleService",
    (__bridge id)kSecValueData: secretPasswordTextData,
    (__bridge id)kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI: @YES,
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject
};

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    OSStatus status =  SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, nil);

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SecItemAdd status: %@", [self keychainErrorToString:status]];

    [self printMessage:message inTextView:self.textView];
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you define secure. Remember, on jailbroken devices any API can be subject to a man in the middle attack. So the backend storage mechanism may be irrelevant. An attacker on a jailbroken device can simply intercept your call to the Keychain API and read any of the arguments you pass to it.

Comment: Colin is right. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548248/is-swift-vulnerable-to-code-injection